# Obtain object name within an object based on it's position using yq

Tags: json, bash, yq

I'm using yq to convert YAML to JSON. When the file is converted it looks like this:

```
{
  "Profiles": {
    "OneOrgOrdererGenesis": {...
    },
    "chan": {...
  }
}
```

Both names of the objects within Profiles will change based on a situation, so I can't look it up by name. I want to obtain the name of 2nd object that's within Profiles object (chan). How can I make this possible using Bash and yq?

Answer (score 1):

here is a command-line to extract it from yaml file:

```
yq r -j zz.yaml Profiles | jq -r 'keys[]'|head -2|tail -1
```

and here is the same method for already converted file:

```
jq -r .Profiles zz.json | jq -r 'keys[]'|head -2|tail -1
```

Both are yielding "SECOND-KEY" value if run on following files:

zz.yaml:

```
Profiles:
   TTT:
      - dfdfd
      - dsdwee
   SECOND-KEY:
      sd:
         - sddsd
   DEE:
      - ds d
      - er er
```

zz.json:

```
{
  "Profiles": {
    "DEE": [
      "ds d",
      "er er"
    ],
    "SECOND-KEY": {
      "sd": [
        "sddsd"
      ]
    },
    "TTT": [
      "dfdfd",
      "dsdwee"
    ]
  }
}
```

first command extracts all children of Profile.

second command extracts top level keys of children.